# Process.Start("url") is not working in proxy environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i can pass WebProxy credentials like userid, password, IP,Port and domain. During proxy environment the url does not open.

Answer (score 2):

The proxy details would have to be setup in the users browser already as `Process.Start("url");` just starts the users browser and uses its current settings.

Comment: +1. `Process.Start` is just an equivalent to typing a url in Start->Run menu